# Orthogonal complements of vectors and null spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Say that for all $p\ge 1$, let $S = \{a_1, ..., a_p\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and write $W=\operatorname{span}(S)$. Then would $W^\bot = \operatorname{Null}(A^T)$ where $A = [a1, ..., ap]$? I would assume yes because $W^\bot$ is the column space of the orthogonal complement? I'm not 100% sure though. I don't know exactly what $W^\bot$ is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: We can revert the question to you. To speak of the orthogonal complement in a vector space, you need to equip it with a bilinear form. So what is the bilinear form you use on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Would that be the transpose of A? I'm not sure what bilinear form is supposed to mean in this context, I haven't learned that term yet.